# How can I sort a Python dictionary sort by key without using Ordereddict?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

What would be a nice way to go from

```
{2:3, 1:89, 4:5, 2:0}
```

to

```
{1:89, 2:3, 2:0, 3:0} ?
```

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary as you mentioned. Because they internally use hashing to store the elements and there is no order as such.

Comment: Can you give an alternative please?

Comment: I want to sort a list of tuples? how to go about it?

Comment: `OrderedDict`, but you don't want that. So, to me, it looks like an impossible thing to do.

Comment: Then please edit your question and make sure that it explicitly says that.

Comment: Also you are using duplicate key. Key should be unique.

Comment: Neither dictionary shown in your question could exist, because they each have an indentical key mapping to two different values (`2:0` & `2:3`) — so that coupled with the fact that dictionaries can't be sorted makes your question completely nonsensical.

Comment: @thefourtheye Wait, what? If something is impossible to do, it should never be asked on SO?

Comment: @frnhr My bad, Sorry.

Comment: @thefourtheye I just wanted to sort a list of tuples, so I convert them to ordered dictionary, I failed to do so back then. But now as per explanations I can accomplish my objective of sorting by both methods: list of tuples and ordereddict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cant have repeated keys in a dict, ordered or otherwise! You have the key `2` twice. One of the two values is going to be lost instantly when the dict is created.

Ok, suppose all the keys are unique. You should never rely on order of items in a dict:

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

(from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html%23mapping-types-dict))

That's why there is OrderedDict. What's the next best thing after OrderedDict? I guess this:

```
>>> d = {2:3, 1:89, 4:5, 2:0, 50: 5, 6: 6}

>>> d  # lost "2:3" pair!
{1: 89, 2: 0, 4: 5, 50: 5, 6: 6}

>>> l = d.items()

>>> l
[(1, 89), (2, 0), (4, 5), (50, 5), (6, 6)]

>>> l.sort()

>>> l
[(1, 89), (2, 0), (4, 5), (6, 6), (50, 5)]
```

That's a list of key-value pairs. It is up to you to take care of fetching values from it, etc. What's important is to **never** do `dict(l)` because that might change the order of items. Even if it seems to work, don't do it! (To be fair: you can do it, just don't rely on order of items in the resulting dict. Or in any other dict for that matter, as stated in the quote above.)

You could implement this in a class, but then you'd be reinventing the OrderedDict class, and probably not as good.

---

Out of curiosity: why you can't use OrderedDict?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you ask for is impossible, because a dictionary is not a linear thing by definition, just like a mathematical set. Probably it uses some kind of tree structure intern, but how it works intern is not important, might change and can be different from implementation to implementation.

On the other hand you are able to produce an ordered representation of a dictionary, e.g. to print it out to show it to a user. One possibility would be to use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#tuples). You can get a list of all items of dictionary with [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). You can use [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) to sort a list.